# Flink windows close time

Tags: java, apache-flink

The code is as follows. According to my understanding, the window will be closed when the watermark is greater than the window end time. But my test results are very confusing.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStreamSource<String> ds = env.socketTextStream("192.168.10.100", 9999);

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<T> map = ds.map(x -> {
            String[] s = x.split(" ");
            return new T(s[0], Integer.parseInt(s[1]));
        });
        WatermarkStrategy<T> wms = WatermarkStrategy.<T>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ZERO)
                .withTimestampAssigner((t, l) -> {
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(10);
                    Date from = Date.from(now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
                    return from.getTime();
                });

        map.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(wms)
                .keyBy(T::getId)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
                .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<T, List<T>, String, TimeWindow>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(String s,
                                        ProcessWindowFunction<T, List<T>, String, TimeWindow>.Context context,
                                        Iterable<T> elements, Collector<List<T>> out) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println(context.window().getStart() + "----" + context.window().getEnd() + "----" + context.window().maxTimestamp());
                        List<T> ts = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (T element : elements) {
                            ts.add(element);
                        }

                        out.collect(ts);
                    }
                }).print();
        env.execute();
    }
}
```

Test Results

1702991405520
1702991406914
1702991408207
1702991409720
1702991411758
1702991413702
1702991414803
1702991418426
1702991419629
1702991420617
1702991421944
1702991423171
1702991424718
1702991426117
1702991427736
1702991429248
1702991405000----1702991410000----1702991409999

The window is 1702991405000----1702991410000,But why does the window close and call the process method when the watermark reaches 1702991429248?

please help me understand

Comment: What does the input to the socket look like?

Comment: It's been solved, thanks. please read my comment

Answer (score 0):

From what you've shared it's not possible to see where 1702991429248 came from, but this value is not the watermark that triggered the window.

Comment: I have not set the parallelism. By default, the number of CPU cores is used. The delivery of watermarks under multiple degrees of parallelism meets the following requirements:                                                                          
 1. Under the condition of multiple degrees of parallelism, the WaterMark is transmitted to the downstream in a broadcast manner.

Comment: 2. The smallest WaterMark is always used! The barrel principle!                                              
 3. And when the watermark value does not increase, it will not Pass downstream, note: the generation remains unchanged.